# How to search columns have specific data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm looking for a way to find column name.

```
v01 | v02 | v03
----+-----+--------
 y  | x   |  y
```

That's how my table looks.

And I want to get `v01, v03` because they have **y**.

Is there any way to get this using SQL?

Comment: You want to return the names of the columns themselves based on the data in them containing a ‘y’?

Comment: What if second row contains `x,y,x` ? how it works and whats the purpose of this requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and concatenate the values together:

```
select ((case when v01 = 'y' then 'v01;' else '' end) +
        (case when v02 = 'y' then 'v02;' else '' end) +
        (case when v03 = 'y' then 'v03;' else '' end)
       )
```

Comment: What if second row contains `x,y,x` ?

Comment: Then it will return `'v02;'`.

Comment: It will return the column names as many as rows in the table so basically we should have have single row as column name otherwise it will display v01, `blank or null` in the same column.

Comment: OH thanks guys. i will have just one row when i search y, cuz there are more columns to make it. by the way i want not just one row but the mount of  columns which have 'y' by row. so... i thought using pivot. but im not good at using it. so do you think any way using pivot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (v01 varchar(10), v02 varchar(10), v03 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'y', 'x', 'y')

SELECT Col FROM @MyTable UNPIVOT( Val FOR Col IN ([v01], [v02], [v03])) UNPVT
WHERE Val = 'y'
```

Result:

```
Col
-------
v01
v03
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Temptable')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Temptable
;WITH cte(
v01 , v02 , v03)
AS
(               
SELECT  'y'  , 'x'   ,  'y'
)
SELECT * INTO Temptable FROM cte
```

By Using cross apply with dynamic sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Getdata')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Getdata
DECLARE @SqlCoulmn NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @SqlCoulmn='SELECT'+ STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ReqriredCOulmns FROM
(
SELECT 'CASE WHEN '+ COLUMN_NAME+'='+'''Y''' + 'THEN '+COLUMN_NAME  +' ELSE NULL END AS '+COLUMN_NAME AS ReqriredCOulmns
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Temptable'
)dt
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') +'  INTO Getdata FROM Temptable'

EXEC (@SqlCoulmn)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) , @dynCoulmn NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @dynCoulmn=STUFF((SELECT distinct ', '+TempCol  FROM
(
SELECT '('+COLUMN_NAME+','+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+')' AS TempCol
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Getdata'
)dt2
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql=' 
SELECT Col FROM Getdata
CROSS APPLY ( Values '+@dynCoulmn+'
            ) A (Val,Col)
            WHERE Val IS NOT NULL
'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result Before Cross apply

```
v01 v02 v03
-----------
y   x   y
```

Result after Cross apply

```
Col
---
v01
v03
```